# I can't connect to mysqlfabric

Tags: mysql-fabric

I can't connect to mysqlfabric on port 32275. 
I am connecting on port 3306 to database so all the grants are in place . On port 32275 I get a message

> ERROR 1044 (42000): [Fabric] Access denied

for user and in log I can see

> [INFO] 1441810699.948011 - MySQL-RPC-Session-4 - User 'john'
>   denied access which suggests permissions issue.

I can log in to database if I use

```
mysql -u fabric -p -h localhost -P 32275
```

but if I use

```
mysql -u fabric -p -h host-ip-address -P 32275
```

I get above error. I can see in netstat that server is listening on that port.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to check in the fabric config.

Firstly try disabling RPC authenication until you have it up and running.

```
[protocol.xmlrpc]
disable_authentication = no
```

Also check your storage section and test you can connect using these settings.

```
[storage]
address = 192.168.0.1:3306
user = fabric_store
password = secret
database = mysql_fabric
auth_plugin = mysql_native_password
```

mysql -u fabric -psecret -h 192.168.0.1 -P 3306 fabric_store